# Probability of choosing r from n where order matters vs where order doesn't matter

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

In Ross's A First Course in Probability (8th Ed), there is an example where 5 people are to be selected from 6 men and 9 women. We want to know the probability of selecting 3 men and 2 women. The answer they give is where we assume order doesn't matter $$\frac{{6 \choose 3}{9 \choose 2}}{15 \choose 5} = \frac{240}{1001}$$ But from other examples in the text, I know I can try to attack this as if order does matter and end up with the same probability. So choosing 5 from 15 will be done in $$15 \times 14 \times 13 \times 12 \times 11$$ ways. The choice of 3 men from 6 is done in $$6 \times 5 \times 4$$ ways and the choice of 2 women from 9 is done in $$9*8$$ ways so the probability is $$\frac{(6 \times 5 \times 4)(9 \times 8)}{15 \times 14 \times 13 \times 12 \times 11} = \frac{24}{1001}$$

Clearly I've done something wrong since I got a different answer, but I can't see it. Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your calculation you are insisting that the men are picked first and the women after.  If you take apart your fraction the first factor is $\frac 6{15}$, which is the chance you pick a man.  There are ${5 \choose 3}=10$ orders to pick three men and two women.  If you multiply your result by that you get the proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Math in this answer is identical to the Math in the answer of Ross Millikan, but the perspective is different.

An alternative approach to resolving the discrepancy is by construing the constraint that order matters as requiring that *adjustments* are made to the numerator and denominator.

Take another look at the original fraction that you know accurately represents the probability of the question:

$$\frac{{6 \choose 3}{9 \choose 2}}{15 \choose 5} \tag1 $$

First, examine the denominator in (1) above.  Assume that order now matters.  Instead of re-computing the denominator, focus on the difference between whether or not order matters.

In the denominator, you originally selected $5$ people, not caring what order that they were selected in.  Once you do care, that means that you can permute the order that these $5$ people were selected in $(5!)$ ways.

So, before any adjustment is made to the numerator, you have the intermediate calculation of

$$\frac{{6 \choose 3}{9 \choose 2}}{15 \choose 5} \times \frac{1}{5!}. \tag2 $$

Notice that in (2) above, the $(5!)$ permutation applies regardless of the gender of the people selected.  That is, you are permuting the people selected in $(5!)$ ways, because exactly $(5)$ people were selected.

So, with respect to the denominator, given the constraint that order matters, you are following a two-step process in the computation.  First, you are selecting the people as if order does not matter.  Then, you are determining the number of ways that these selections can be permuted, since order does now matter.

---

Now, consider the numerator.  The numerator and denominator must be computed in a similar manner.  The numerator also represents the selection of $(5)$ people, of various genders.  When the constraint is imposed that order of selection matters, it is not the order that the men were selected that matters, or the order that the women were selected that matters.

Instead, to be consistent with the adjustment made in the denominator, when computing the numerator, you have to assume that what matters is the order that the $(5)$ people as a whole were selected, regardless of the gender of the selected people.

So, the consideration of the numerator and adjustment to the numerator parallels the focus on the denominator.  In the numerator, $(5)$ people were selected, and since order of selection matters, the order that these $(5)$ people were selected can be permuted in $(5!)$ ways.

Therefore, you have the final adjustment of

$$\frac{{6 \choose 3}{9 \choose 2}}{15 \choose 5} \times \frac{1}{5!} \times \frac{5!}{1}. \tag3 $$

So, with respect to the numerator, given the constraint that order matters, you are again following a two-step process in the computation.  First, you are selecting the people as if order does not matter.  Then, you are determining the number of ways that these selections can be permuted, since order does now matter.